# Android filterable recyclerview with checkboxes

Tags: android, android-layout, search, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I am developing an app in which i have `RecyclerView` with checkboxes and a searchview.For searching from edit text i have added

[image]

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

and in `afterTextChanged()` i am changing list and calling `notifydatasetChanged()`

but state of checkboxes are lost after search.is there any way to keep checkboxes state?

Comment: can u share the source code??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can create ArrayList and save all selected items in that array. After notify list you can check that id`s , if its (contains)available in that array list then you will just checked that checkbox using setChecked(true);

For example:

```
// Creating and adding data in arraylist
ArrayList<String> selectedCat = new ArrayList<String>();
selectedCat.add('Your-selected-id');

//Checked array list item and placed in binder method
if(selectedCat.contains("Your-current-ids")){
  your-checkbox-object.setChecked(true);
}else{
  your-checkbox-object.setChecked(false);
}
```

Comment: Perfectly answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create Boolean array first with false value in adapter.If user checks the array, then make array's position true and On uncheck make it false. Later on always set the checkbox value from that Boolean array.

For more see this one

http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/01/recyclerview-with-checkbox-example.html

[Onscroll selected checkbox getting unchecked using listiview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35552911/4407266)