# SetOnCheckedChangedListener is firing scrolling android

Tags: android

In my custom listview, I have a check box, couple of TextViews etc. I need to implement check event of this check box.
If I used, setOnCheckedChangeListener of the check box, it fires when scrolling the listview. Then I used setOnClickListener, but still I some items are un-checked when I am scrolling the list. Someone has advised to do as below link,
[CheckBox gets unchecked on scroll in a custom listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309250/checkbox-gets-unchecked-on-scroll-in-a-custom-listview)

But there it is only considering the Check box as the listview item. Isn't it? I have multiple controls such as check box, text view, editview in my custom list view item. Could you please help?

```
public class DocumentRegisterAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<Document> objects;
public int selectedItem=-1;
Context context;
String x="";
String prev = "";

private final boolean[] mCheckedState;

public DocumentRegisterAdapter(Context context1,ArrayList<Document> objects) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context1);
    this.objects = objects;
    context = context1;

    mCheckedState = new boolean[objects.size()];
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

public void setList(ArrayList<Document> objects){
    this.objects=objects;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null) {
        //convertView = inflater.inflate(R parent, false);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.document_register_cell,parent,false);
    }

    final CheckBox chkCheckin = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);


    if (((DashboardActivity)context).isCalledCheckOut ||((DashboardActivity)context).isCalledCheckIn)
    {

        chkCheckin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (GlobalVariables.getGsCurrentFragment() == Constants.documentRegistryFragment) {
            if (chkCheckin.isChecked()) {
                chkCheckin.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
        //chkCheckin.setChecked(false);


    }
    else
    {
        chkCheckin.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    }

    chkCheckin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(chkCheckin.isChecked())
            {
                ((DashboardActivity) context).checkInOutDocument = new Document(objects.get(position).documentNo, objects.get(position).documenttitle, objects.get(position).revision, objects.get(position).category, objects.get(position).discipline, objects.get(position).status, objects.get(position).type, objects.get(position).fileFormat, objects.get(position).checkOut, objects.get(position).intKey, objects.get(position).getReason(), "1", objects.get(position).isSelected());
                ((DashboardActivity) context).checkInOutDocList.add(((DashboardActivity) context).checkInOutDocument);
                ((DashboardActivity) context).pos.put(Integer.toString(position), Integer.toString(((DashboardActivity) context).checkInOutDocList.size() - 1));

            }
            else
            {
                Iterator itr = ((DashboardActivity) context).checkInOutDocList.iterator();
                Document strElement = null;
                while(itr.hasNext()) {

                    strElement = (Document) itr.next();
                    if (strElement.documentNo.equals(objects.get(position).documentNo)) {
                            itr.remove();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    });

   TextView txtDocumentNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblDocumentNo);
    TextView txtDocumentTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblDocumentTitle);
    TextView txtRevision = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblRevVal);
    TextView txtCategory = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblCategoryVal);
    TextView txtDiscipline = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblDisciplineVal);
    TextView txtStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblStatusVal);
    TextView txttype = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblTitleVal);
    TextView txtFileFormat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblFileFormatVal);
    ImageView imgCheckOut = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgCheckout);
    ImageButton imgBtnAttachment = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);


    txtDocumentNo.setText(objects.get(position).documentNo);
    txtDocumentTitle.setText(objects.get(position).documenttitle);
    txtRevision.setText(objects.get(position).revision);
    txtCategory.setText(objects.get(position).category);
    txtDiscipline.setText(objects.get(position).discipline);
    txtStatus.setText(objects.get(position).status);
    txttype.setText(objects.get(position).type);
    txtFileFormat.setText(objects.get(position).fileFormat);

    if (objects.get(position).checkOut == 0){
        imgCheckOut.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        //Anu 2016/03/03
        if(((DashboardActivity)context).isCalledCheckOut)
            chkCheckin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else if(((DashboardActivity)context).isCalledCheckIn)
            chkCheckin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        Drawable d = convertView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tb_checkout);
        imgCheckOut.setImageDrawable(d);

        imgCheckOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(((DashboardActivity)context).isCalledCheckOut)
            chkCheckin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        else if(((DashboardActivity)context).isCalledCheckIn)
            chkCheckin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    if (objects.get(position).fileFormat.length() > 0) {
```

//            Drawable d = convertView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tbattachment3);
//            imgBtnAttachment.setImageDrawable(d);

```
        imgBtnAttachment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        imgBtnAttachment.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    imgBtnAttachment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // ((DashboardActivity) context).throughAttButton = true;

            ((DashboardActivity) context).attachmentState=0;
            ((DashboardActivity) context).currentAttachment = 0;

            ((DashboardActivity)context).transmittalAttViewModule = Constants.documentModule;

            DocumentServices documentServices = new DocumentServices();
            List<Map<String,String>> docAttachmentsList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

            ((DashboardActivity) context).transmittalDocIntKey = objects.get(position).intKey;

            ((DashboardActivity) context).currentlyDownloadingFileInfo.put("IntKey", objects.get(position).intKey + "");
            ((DashboardActivity)context).currentlyDownloadingFileInfo.put("Box", Constants.DeviceInfoBox.DOCUMENT.getValue()+"");

            if(GlobalVariables.getGsDeviceAccessMode().equals(Constants.constOnline)) {
                docAttachmentsList = documentServices.ListViewFilesForDownload(context, objects.get(position).intKey);
            }else{
                docAttachmentsList = documentServices.ListViewFilesForOfflineDownload(context, objects.get(position).intKey);
            }

            ((DashboardActivity) context).revisedAttachmentList = new ArrayList<>();
            if(docAttachmentsList.size()>0){
                for (int k = 0; k < docAttachmentsList.size(); k++) {
                    ((DashboardActivity) context).revisedAttachmentList.add(docAttachmentsList.get(k));
                }
            }


            selectedItem = position;
            ((DashboardActivity) context).callTransmittalAttachment(0);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


    if(position%2 == 0)
    {
        String myHexColor = "#f8f2f2f2";
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(myHexColor));
    }
    else
    {
        String myHexColor = "#ffffff";
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(myHexColor));
    }

    if(selectedItem!=-1&&selectedItem==position){
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#969696"));
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: Please see my Adapter class.

Comment: @creativePro you put all findViewById inside if(convert==null) also use setTag and getTag its because of view when scrolled goes away from the view you are facing the problem

Comment: Hi Sayyaf, could you please explain how to use setTag and getTag please?